# How to ignore everything in the document environment?

Tags: environments

Yes, you did read the title correctly!

I want to ignore *everything* that is between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` when I `\input` a file.  I thought that that would be very simple, just use [the `environ` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

```
\RenewEnviron{document}{}
```

But it turn out not be that easy.
The MWE below yields the correct results:

[image]

but only with the comments intact. If you un-comment the commented lines then end up with:

> LaTeX Error: \env@document@save@env undefined

Interestingly, ignoring this error one can continue past this, and still get the correct results. :-)

### Notes:

- I realize that in there can be other things in the preamble, so this is by no means a general solution. For the places where I need this functionality, the preamble *only* has `\documentclass` and two `\input`/`\usepackage` which loads all the `.sty` files needed so this will suffice for my needs.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{standalone}

\newtoks{\MyToken}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.tex}
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{MyStandardPackages}

    \MyToken={foo}

%   \begin{document}
%       lots of text here
%
%       \SetSomeVarable{\SomeVar}{Some Value}
%       
%       \begin{SomeEnvironment}
%           lots more stuff here as well
%       \end{SomeEnvironment}
%   \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\MyToken={XXX}


\newcommand{\DisablePreamble}{%
    \renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][]{}%  remove def'n of \documentclass
    \renewcommand{\usepackage}[2][]{}%     ignore any \usepackage{}
%   \RenewEnviron{document}{}% Ignore everything within the "document" environment.
}%

\newcommand*{\ExtractMyToken}[1]{%
    \begingroup% What happens in the group stays in the group!
        \DisablePreamble%
        \input{#1}%
        \global\MyToken=\expandafter{\the\MyToken}%
    \endgroup%
}%

\begin{document}
MyToken=\the\MyToken

\ExtractMyToken{foo}

MyToken=\the\MyToken
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure about the tags on this question. Feel free to edit them if anyone thinks of better tags.

Comment: What is the practical application of this type of behavior?

Comment: @cslstr: I have numerous files with a standard header and I use tokens to specify meta data for each file _before_ `\begin{document}`. I needed to extract this meta data (but none of the content) in another file. Typically this kind of stuff is done in TeX via an `.aux` file but I was trying to avoid a temporary file, and just extract the data directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common problem with [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ), and the way I get around it is to define those commands it has a problem with:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\env@document@save@env}{}% To keep environ happy
\providecommand{\env@document@process}{}%
\RenewEnviron{document}{}% Ignore everything within the "document" environment.
\makeatother
```

A quick-and-dirty way of achieving what you're after is to use

```
\renewcommand{\document}{\endgroup\endinput}
```

which terminates the reading of the `\input` document as soon as it reaches `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Works great. Can you elaborate on "not clean" comment.

Comment: @PeterGrill: You don't have to, but it's cleaner to close the group started by `\begin`.

Answer (score 5):

I'd (locally) define

```
\def\begin#1{\endinput}`
```

so the file stops at that point, or perhaops (I didn't understand your use case really

```
 \def\documentclass[#1]#2{\endinput}
```

and stop even earlier (but if you are doing that just not inputting the file would be easier)

Comment: Not sure I understand you first bit of code. Did you mean `\def\document{\endinput}`? I just want to disable the `document` environment, so want everything _before_ `\begin{document}` to be executed, with `\documentclass` and `\usepackage` being the only exceptions.

Comment: @PeterGrill well  I meant what I wrote you could fudge `\document` instead but I did `\begin` it's rare to have any environment before document so stopping at the first \begin seemed reasonable

Comment: Ahh, I see. Yes, stopping at the first `\begin` should be fine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: [`filecontents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) could be a problem with such a redefinition, since it relies on `\begin`...`\end` constructs.