# How to generalize a solution with \NewEnviron to \RenewEnviron (error: \env@proof@save@env undefined)

Tags: environments

This question is a follow-up from
[Solution environment via true/false switch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172404/solution-environment-via-true-false-switch)
where Ian helped me to define a solution environment which can be hidden. I
tried it as well for a proof environment, but `proof` is already defined. I
tried to work with `\RenewEnviron` and followed
[How to ignore everything in the document environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165258/how-to-ignore-everything-in-the-document-environment)
to get past the first error, but now I get `LaTeX Error: \env@proof@save@env undefined`. I am looking for a fix (rather than a suggestion to stick with the
already defined environment or to use a different name).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifshowproof
\showprooftrue

% proof environment
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\env@document@save@env}{}%
\providecommand{\env@document@process}{}%
\RenewEnviron{proof}[1][showproof]{%
  \csname if#1\endcsname
    \trivlist
    \item\relax{\sffamily\bfseries Proof}\par\noindent
    \BODY
    \endtrivlist
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Proof with hide feature:
\begin{proof}[false]
  This should not appear
\end{proof}

Proof without hide feature:
\begin{proof}
  This should appear
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest `\let\proof\relax\let\endproof\relax` and to remove the useless `\providecommand` instructions.

Comment: Hi Enrico, where do you put the `\let\proof...` statement at? instead of the `\providecommand` or inside? I tried various versions but they give me errors.

Comment: Now `\RenewEnviron` should become `\NewEnviron`.

Comment: Ahh, great, thanks! (do you want to post it so that I can accept it?)

Comment: This will be fixed in v0.3 of environ, just submitted to CTAN. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, `\RenewEnviron` has never worked. The only way I know to make it work is to undefine the previous commands and use `\NewEnviron`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifshowproof
\showprooftrue

% proof environment
% remove the meaning of \proof and \endproof
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
% now we can redefine proof
\NewEnviron{proof}[1][showproof]{%
  \csname if#1\endcsname
    \trivlist
    \item\relax{\sffamily\bfseries Proof}\par\noindent
    \BODY
    \endtrivlist
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
Proof with hide feature:
\begin{proof}[false]
  This should not appear
\end{proof}

Proof without hide feature:
\begin{proof}
  This should appear
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

However, I would retain the original `proof` environment, so the QED mechanism remains in place.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{environ,letltxmacro}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifshowproof
\showprooftrue

% proof environment
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\amsthmproof\proof
\LetLtxMacro\amsthmendproof\endproof
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\NewEnviron{proof}[1][showproof]{%
  \csname if#1\endcsname
    \amsthmproof[\normalfont\bfseries Proof\spacefactor3000 ]
    \BODY
    \amsthmendproof
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Proof with hide feature:
\begin{proof}[false]
  This should not appear
\end{proof}

Proof without hide feature:
\begin{proof}
  This should appear
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Remove the `\spacefactor3000` bit (don't forget the space, otherwise) if you want the full stop after **Proof**.

If you ***really*** want a line break after **Proof** (but you shouldn't), add `\mbox{}\par\noindent` after the closing bracket.

[image]

Comment: As you know, I'm not an expert here. But I think with `\pushQED{\qed}` before `\csname` and `\popQED` before `\endtrivlist`, one can get the qedsymbol as well.

Comment: I posted a follow-up question which shows that a `\label{}` introduces an additional horizontal space (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173664/horizontal-space-in-a-new-environment-after-label)

Comment: @MariusHofert Yes, of course. That's because you want a new line after **Proof**, which you don't want, do you? `;-)`

Comment: ahh... of course... my hope was that a label does not change the spacing, but apparently it does. hmmm... I would like the new line after the label in case there is one :-)

Comment: @MariusHofert Besides, what does a `\label` do there?

Comment: good point. To refer to the page where the proof starts :-) [this is in a large document and I saw that some of the proofs had a label]