# Horizontal space in a new environment after \label{}

Tags: spacing, environments

Why is the horizontal space inserted in the following mwe?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% proof environment
\makeatletter
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\NewEnviron{proof}[1][true]{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \csname if#1\endcsname
    \trivlist
    \item\relax{\sffamily\bfseries Proof}\par\noindent
    \BODY
    \popQED\endtrivlist
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Just some text
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}\label{foo}
  Just some text (after a label)
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[true]
  Just some text after optional argument true
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try ending the line as `\label{foo}%%` to avoid the unwanted additional whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a construct such as `\par\noindent` getting spurious space in the output is inevitable, `\label` just happens to be the trigger here but the real issue is that you have started horizontal mode too early, and in horizontal mode white space makes a word space. You can see that `\label` is not really involved if you change your original document to have `\begin{proof}{}` just the `{}` is enough to get the bad space you don't need `\label{foo}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% proof environment
\makeatletter
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\NewEnviron{proof}[1][true]{%
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \csname if#1\endcsname
    \trivlist
\labelsep\z@
\def\makelabel##1{\makebox[\linewidth][l]{##1}}%
    \item[\sffamily\bfseries Proof]%
    \BODY
    \popQED\endtrivlist
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{proof}
  Just some text\\hhh
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}\label{foo}
  Just some text (after a label)
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[true]
  Just some text after optional argument true
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK now it's my turn to be baffled.  I would have thought, even with your approach, that `\label{...}` ending a line or any atom such as `{}` ending the line without a terminal `%` would still result in unwanted space popping up.  What's happening?

Comment: @A.Ellett tex is in vertical mode after an item label, as it is after section headings and anywhere else Latex expects you to use `\label`.

Comment: But even when I place `{}` as the first content after the beginning of the proof environment, I still don't get extra space.  Shouldn't `{}` be starting horizontal mode?

Comment: @A.Ellett well it doesn't: (it just opens and closes a group) "should" is a judgement on Knuth's design and I wouldn't do that:-)

Comment: Wow.  I'm apparently transgressing rather badly today.  ;P

Comment: @A.Ellett the extra space was because the OP had started horizontal mode with `\noindent` so that is just like going `one {} two` you get _two word spaces.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX is notoriously finicky about whitespace at the end of lines.

So to avoid extra white space from creeping in it can help to add a comment at the end of the *offending* line.

```
\label{foo}%%
```

Generally it is safe to end the line with a control sequence such as

```
\bfseries
```

But anything other than a control sequence will result in additional whitespace added to your page.  The only place where LaTeX *usually* ignores white space is at the beginning of a line.  (I say usually because in certain contexts such as `verbatim` environments and their ilk, this is not the case.)

Comment: hey don't blame latex: if the user asks for space, that's what the user gets:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Perhaps by *finicky* I mean, LaTeX does exactly as you tell it to do.  So I guess I'm just stating the obvious:  LaTeX is as LaTeX does.  ;)

Comment: OK you're forgiven then

Answer (score 1):

If you ***really, really*** want a line break after **Proof**, then use a different approach, with the help of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{environ,letltxmacro,enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newif\ifshowproof
\showprooftrue

% proof environment
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\NewEnviron{proof}[1][showproof]{%
  \csname if#1\endcsname
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \description[topsep=6pt plus 6pt,style=nextline,leftmargin=0pt,font=\bfseries]
    \item[Proof]
    \BODY
    \popQED\enddescription
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
Proof with hide feature:
\begin{proof}[false]\label{x}
  This should not appear
\end{proof}

Proof without hide feature:
\begin{proof}\label{y}
  This should appear
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, please, have mercy of your readers. `;-)`

Comment: Hi, thanks. This does not introduce a line break if the proof starts with an `enumerate` environment :-(

Comment: @MariusHofert This seems a bug of `enumitem`. I'd like to help you, but I won't pursue this any more: I firmly believe that (1) the label “Proof” should not be boldface; (2) the label should not be in a line by itself; (3) no proof should be a big `enumerate` environment.