# Output Content ONLY from a Single Macro

Tags: conditionals

I want a mode where the output consists of ONLY a *single macro*. In the MWE below, that is the output of `\ImportantMacro`. *All* other text outside of this macro is to be ignored.

An obvious start to this problem is to redfine the non `\ImportantMacro`s when in this mode:

```
\ifdefined\OnlyOutputImportantMacro% Redefine all macros to be ignored.
    \renewcommand{\MacroToBeIgnored}[1]{}%
\fi
```

but, what about text that is not in a macro?  The MWE below outputs:

[image]

where all the text in red should be suppressed, and *only* text in blue should be output.

### Somewhat Related References:

- [Can one TeX file output to multiple PDF files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5228/4301)
- [How to ignore everything in the document environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165258/4301)

### Bonus:

- Is there an easier method than redefining *all* the macros that are not the *one* macro that I am interested in?
- Is it possible to ignore a macro in the main document, yet *not* ignore it if it appears *within* the `\ImportantMacro`. Of coure I could do the brute force method of setting a flag when entering `\ImportantMacro` and then conditionally ignoring the macro unless the flag is set. Or redefining macros when within `\ImportantMacro`:

  ```
  \newcommand{\ImportantMacro}[1]{%
      \ifdefined\OnlyOutputImportantMacro
          \renewcommand{\MacroToBeIgnored}[1]{\begingroup\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries##1}\endgroup}%  BONUS
      \fi
      \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
      \ifdefined\OnlyOutputImportantMacro
          \renewcommand{\MacroToBeIgnored}[1]{}%
      \fi
  }%
  ```

  is not really a practical option.
  Wondering if there is a more TeXish way to do this. This is the **bold** blue text in the output.

### Code:

```
\def\OnlyOutputImportantMacro{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand{\MacroToBeIgnored}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}%
\newcommand{\ImportantMacro}[1]{%
    \ifdefined\OnlyOutputImportantMacro
        \renewcommand{\MacroToBeIgnored}[1]{\begingroup\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries##1}\endgroup}%  BONUS
    \fi
    \textcolor{blue}{#1}%
    \ifdefined\OnlyOutputImportantMacro
        \renewcommand{\MacroToBeIgnored}[1]{}%
    \fi
}%

\ifdefined\OnlyOutputImportantMacro% Redefine all macros to be ignored.
    \renewcommand{\MacroToBeIgnored}[1]{}%
\fi

\begin{document}\color{red}
Some text outside of macro that needs to be ignored.
\MacroToBeIgnored{%
    Some text inside of macro that needs to be ignored.%
}
\ImportantMacro{%
    Some text inside of macro that needs to be output.
    \MacroToBeIgnored{Bonus text not to be suppressed.}%
}
\MacroToBeIgnored{%
    Some text inside of macro that needs to be ignored.%
}
Some more text outside of macro that needs to be ignored.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could look at how Beamer implements `ignorenonframetext`.

Answer (score 6):

Proof of concept:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\ImportantMacro[1]{%
  \gdef\ImportantMacroArg{#1}%
  \aftergroup\ImportantMacroArg
}
\AtBeginDocument{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}
\AtEndDocument{\egroup}

\begin{document}

whatever you want
\ImportantMacro{This will print}
some other text

\end{document}
```

You're trying to stretch too much, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmmm.. This looks promising...