# Paper - Hide everything except for the outputs from one command

Tags: formatting, color

In the following code, I can hide in the paper any piece of text except the ones coming from the command `\showthis`.

**Is there a way to hide output coming from other materials like pictures and tikz drawings for example ?**

This would be to do a preprocessing for a tool to automate corrections of tests.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
  \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{white}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\showthis{{\color{black} JUST SHOW ME}}

\newcommand\blabla{bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\showthis{}

\lipsum[2]

\showthis{}

\blabla{} \showthis{} \blabla{}

\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hide on paper or in the PDF?  For example, your approach hides the text on paper, but it still exists in the PDF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output Content ONLY from a Single Macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418486/output-content-only-from-a-single-macro)

Comment: I have edited my question. I am only concerned by the paper version.

Comment: If only the paper version is the issue, then why isn't what you have already done (in the example provided in your question) good enough?

Comment: My example doesn’t take care of none textual materials.

Answer (score 1):

Is it something like thqt you are looking for ?

**Hidetrue**

[image]

**Hidefalse**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newif\ifHide
\Hidetrue % hide the text 
%\Hidefalse % show the text

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{Hidethis}{%
    \ifHide
    \begingroup\color{white}
    \fi}{%
    \ifHide
    \endgroup
    \fi}

\newcommand\blabla{bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla...}


\begin{document}

\begin{Hidethis}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Hidethis}

JUST SHOW ME

\begin{Hidethis}
\blabla{}
\end{Hidethis}
JUST SHOW ME
\begin{Hidethis}
\blabla{}
\end{Hidethis}

\begin{Hidethis}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Hidethis}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this solution is only for text. How can I manage pictures and other none textual materials.

Comment: @projetmbc do you the hidden parts disappear and take no more room or turn white but stay in place.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I am looking for a soft solution which uses a macro for the parts to be displayed instead of a macro for things to be hidden.

Comment: @projetmbc OK but do you want that the displayed parts stay at there places (hidden text takes his room) or hidden text vanishes and the displayed parts stick together? Am I clear ?

Comment: @Tarras Yes I want that hidden texts take their room.

Comment: I have it in mind. I'll post if I'll found something.